# Oracle SQL with if else structure

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table like following.

Table name : **myTable**

[image]

Logic: if married = 1 we should retreivew the salary value (200) and if married = 0 we should get food value.

Tried using decode but no success.

How to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need a case expression :

```
SELECT Road,CASE WHEN maried = 1 then salary else food end as NewValue
FROM(select Road,
            max(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'maried' then value end) as maried,
            max(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'salary' then value end) as salary,
            max(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'food' then value end) as food
     FROM myTable
     GROUP BY Road)
```

This will give you for each unique ROAD your LOGIC.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? @AsiriLiyanaArachchi